# UPDATED: Laravel View [] not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to open a /messages page which displays a table linking to some CRUD methods/views but am getting a not found error, I have attached a screenshot of my mysql page which shows the data i'm trying to save, I feel asthough I have not done the controller correctly and am getting the error. However when I put a fully working one in I still get the view not found. inside my web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web', 'role:admin'], 'namespace' => '\App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController', [
        'names' => [
            'index'   => 'messages',
            'destroy' => 'message.destroy',
        ],
    ]);
    Route::post('search-messages', '\App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController@search')->name('search-messages');
```

my view is inside the resources/views/messages.blade.php and all my views look to be in order, here is my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    private $_authEnabled;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_authEnabled = config('laravelmessages.authEnabled');
        if ($this->_authEnabled) {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pagintaionEnabled = config('laravelmessages.enablePagination');

        if ($pagintaionEnabled) {
            $messages = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::paginate(config('laravelmessages.paginateListSize'));
        } else {
            $messages = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::all();
        }

        $data = [
            'messages' => $messages,
            'pagintaionEnabled' => $pagintaionEnabled,
        ];

        return view(config('laravelmessages.showmessagesBlade'), $data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view(config('laravelmessages.createmessageBlade'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = [
            'direction.required' => trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.messageDirectionRequired'),
            'account_id.required' => 'account_id is required',
            'recipient_id.required' => trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.recipient_idRequired'),
            'content_id.email' => trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.content_idInvalid'),
            'source_id.required' => trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.source_idRequired'),
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $message = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::create([
            'account_id' => $request->input('account_id'),
            'recipient_id' => $request->input('recipient_id'),
            'content_id' => $request->input('content_id'),
            'source_id' => bcrypt($request->input('source_id')),
        ]);

        return redirect('messages')->with('success', trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.message-creation-success'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $message = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::find($id);

        return view(config('laravelmessages.showIndividualmessageBlade'))->withmessage($message);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $message = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::findOrFail($id);
        $data = [
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        return view(config('laravelmessages.editIndividualmessageBlade'))->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $message = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::find($id);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $message->save();

        return back()->with('success', trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.update-message-success'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $currentmessage = Auth::message();
        $message = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::findOrFail($id);

        if ($currentmessage->id != $message->id) {
            $message->delete();

            return redirect('messages')->with('success', trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.delete-success'));
        }

        return back()->with('error', trans('laravelmessages::laravelmessages.messages.cannot-delete-yourself'));
    }

    /**
     * Method to search the messages.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->input('message_search_box');
        $searchRules = [
            'message_search_box' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];
        $searchMessages = [
            'message_search_box.required' => 'Search term is required',
            'message_search_box.string' => 'Search term has invalid characters',
            'message_search_box.max' => 'Search term has too many characters - 255 allowed',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $searchRules, $searchMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                json_encode($validator),
            ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }

        $results = config('laravelmessages.defaultmessageModel')::where('id', 'like', $searchTerm . '%')
            ->orWhere('account_id', 'like', $searchTerm . '%')
            ->orWhere('content_id', 'like', $searchTerm . '%')
            ->orWhere('status_id', 'like', $searchTerm . '%')->get();

        return response()->json([
            json_encode($results),
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

laravelmessages.php inside my config file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel-messages setting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // The parent blade file
    'laravelmessagesBladeExtended'     => 'adminlte::page', //'laravelmessages::layouts.app', // 'layouts.app'

    // Enable `auth` middleware
    'authEnabled'                   => true,

    // Enable Optional Roles Middleware on the messages assignments
    'rolesEnabled'                  => true,

    /*
     | Enable Roles Middlware on the usability of this package.
     | This requires the middleware from the roles package to be registered in `App\Http\Kernel.php`
     | An Example: of roles middleware entry in protected `$routeMiddleware` array would be:
     | 'role' => \jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\Middleware\VerifyRole::class,
     */

    'rolesMiddlwareEnabled'         => true,

//    // Optional Roles Middleware
//    'rolesMiddlware'                => 'role:admin',
//
//    // Optional Role Model
//    'roleModel'                     => 'jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\Models\Role',

    // Enable Soft Deletes - Not yet setup - on the roadmap. -- Im lazy on this :P - jk
    'softDeletedEnabled'            => false,

    // Laravel Default message Model
    'defaultMessageModel'              => 'App\Message',

    // Use the provided blade templates or extend to your own templates.
    'showmessagesBlade'                => 'messagesmanagement.show-messages', //'laravelmessages::messagesmanagement.show-messages',
    'createmessageBlade'               => 'messagesmanagement.create-message', //'laravelmessages::messagesmanagement.create-message',
    'showIndividualmessageBlade'       => 'messagesmanagement.show-message', // 'laravelmessages::messagesmanagement.show-message',
    'editIndividualmessageBlade'       => 'messagesmanagement.edit-message', //'laravelmessages::messagesmanagement.edit-message',


    // Use Package Bootstrap Flash Alerts
    'enablePackageBootstapAlerts'   => true,

    // messages List Pagination
    'enablePagination'              => true,
    'paginateListSize'              => 25,

    // Enable Search messages- Uses jQuery Ajax
    'enableSearchmessages'             => true,

    // messages List JS DataTables - not recommended use with pagination
    'enabledDatatablesJs'           => false,
    'datatablesJsStartCount'        => 25,
    'datatablesCssCDN'              => 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css',
    'datatablesJsCDN'               => 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
    'datatablesJsPresetCDN'         => 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js',

    // Bootstrap Tooltips
    'tooltipsEnabled'               => true,
    'enableBootstrapPopperJsCdn'    => true,
    'bootstrapPopperJsCdn'          => 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js',

    // Icons
    'fontAwesomeEnabled'            => true,
    'fontAwesomeCdn'                => 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css',

    // Extended blade options for packages app.blade.php
    'enableBootstrapCssCdn'         => true,
    'bootstrapCssCdn'               => 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',

    'enableAppCss'                  => true,
    'appCssPublicFile'              => 'css/app.css',

    'enableBootstrapJsCdn'          => true,
    'bootstrapJsCdn'                => 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',

    'enableAppJs'                   => true,
    'appJsPublicFile'               => 'js/app.js',

    'enablejQueryCdn'               => true,
    'jQueryCdn'                     => 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',

];
```

I have tried playing around with my controller and views but don't seem to be having any luck I also tried and clearing the config through:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this would be greatly appreciated, anything further I can provide I will gladly do so :)

[image: XXamp phpMyAdmin]

Comment: `config:clear` to clear the cached config ... seems like one of those config values you are using for a view name doesn't have a value

Comment: Use `dd(config('laravelmessages'));` to see all available config options for `laravelmessages`. One of the `config('laravelmessages.{view}')` is `null` or `empty` (`''`), but it's impossible for us to tell without you showing the full error message and posting the contents of that config file.

Comment: in your index function there is a few typo: $pagintaionEnabled. It would be pagination I think.

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. Please provide more information about your code details

Comment: Change `return view(config('laravelmessages.showmessagesBlade'), $data);` to `return view('laravelmessages.showmessagesBlade', compact('data');` 
    }

Comment: Hello guys, I tried the `config:clear` but didn't seem to work, I put the dd method in but don't really know where to put it if I'm honest I have paste my laravelmessages config file into my question. I also found that a lot of the data I was requesting inside my controller was user data, not message data, I pasted in an image of my xxamp structure too

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem was for this so I recorded the application and it's working fine now